# Disable stack trace in JUNIT reports created by TestNG

Tags: selenium, junit, testng

I want to disable the stack trace in junit reports created by testng. Whenever tests are run via maven surefire + testng, it creates junit xml reports automatically. 
Now I am creating html report from these xml files (using apache ant build) and embedding it directly in email body (email sent via jenkins). But the problem is, it contains long stack trace which is of no use to stack holders or other non technical users. 
How can I disable these stack traces ? Is there any way we can implement the listeners of junit reporter in testng or some other way ?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: JUNIT REPORT WITH STACKTRACE]

Comment: I tried to create a custom junit reporter by implementing IResultListener2 (which is being implemented by JUnitXMLReporter class in org.testng.reporter package). Added this new class as a listener in the testng suite. It is working but the problem is, JUnitXMLReporter class is also listening and overwriting the result of custom reporter. So the report is still the same. Any way to disable this JUnitXMLReporter listener ?

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit digging into testng and maven, the way I found to disable the JUnitReportReporter is to disable all default listeners in testng and attach the wanted listeners + your own customized JUnitReportReporter.

Below is the snapshot from POM.xml file of my project. Just focus on the part -- 'usedefaultlisteners' property defined in properties tag.

[image]

Hope it will help someone looking for the similar question.